# QGIS geoprocessing script, ## hand-over processing-specific information error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a QGIS python geoprocessing script starting like this:

```
## Networking = group
## lIn = vector
## lOut = output vector

from qgis.core import *

v = processing.getObject(lIn)

#[...the rest...]
```

Executing it make a wonderful gui

[image]

but clicking 'Run' gives me an error

[image]

What am I probably missing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to **not include spaces** when defining your parameters:

```
##Networking=group
##lIn=vector
#lOut=output vector

from qgis.core import *

v = processing.getObject(lIn)

#[...the rest...]
```

If you run the above code now (notice I commented out the output vector since nothing is being passed to it), it should run without errors.